# Molarity of solids and liquids in equilibrium constant expression

Tags: equilibrium

Why  is the molarity of pure liquids , solids and excess solvent taken 1 in the equilibrium constant expression?

Comment: [It's not supposed to be a molarity, it's supposed to be an activity.](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40567/) And, [activities of pure liquids and solids are by definition 1.](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59287/)